# TFS for web designers

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are a small design agency based on .net. The devs use VS and TFS. Is there a way of setting up the designer with some kind of way of getting source code and building it on their machines without the full version of VS which is pretty expensive for people who only want to change CSS and odd bit of HTML. The designers currently use Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010 Express does not have a support for TFS.

But now you can use Visual Studio 11 Express which supports TFS.

[Visual Studio 11 Express Features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2012/03/22/visual-studio-11-express-beta-for-web-new-features.aspx)

Comment: That's right, and Microsoft support "Go Live" which mean you can use Visual Studio 11 Beta now in production: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads/go-live   you can also Download the TFS Express from here :http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#tfs-express

Answer (score 1):

In TFS2010, you can install the Team Explorer and use your favorite file editing tool. The designer then only needs a TFS CAL to connect to the TFS server.